# Incomplete and imperfect list of reasons for closing a question

Tags: discussion, moderation

Why on earth the most obvious reason - that is, that question is off-topic, 
is not present in this list? Is it something community-specific or should we request changes on a Stackexchange level?

[image]

Comment: It's on a Stackexchange level, I'm afraid. On the other hand, all the reasons describe the "off-topic" somehow.

Comment: @Dmitry let's discuss more specifically - in your opinion to which category belongs this particular question? - https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/22365/why-are-there-three-genders-in-russian

I do realise you are not arguing - I'm just trying to weigh in the possibility of asking on a general meta.

Comment: I'd say it is "Needs details..." or "Opinion-based".

Answer (score 2):

Choose "Community-specific reasons" and you'll see more options:

[image]

You can even add your own favourite reason.

Comment: question being off-topic is not a community-specific reason )

Comment: A question being off-topic _on Russian Language_, at which the title of that dialog hints, is.